# Can I download a bucket from GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine

Basically, I'm migrating from GAE to AWS. I have a bucket on GAE and I'd like to download all the files. I can't seem to find the command. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [copy all files](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) using gsutil.